# Rails 4 - how to fetch IDs of categories from array and put them to the <SELECT> tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, associations

In controller, I load data from database:

```
@events = Event.where("active = '1' AND event_start < ? AND event_start > ?", Date.today+1, Date.today-5).order(created_at: :desc).group_by { |r| r.event_start.to_date }
```

And in the respective view:

```
#events
    = render partial: "/events/event", locals: { e: @events}
```

`_event.html.haml`:

```
- e.each do |key, arr|
  - arr.map(&:category_id).each do |category_id|
    %div= Category.find(category_id).category_name
```

In the partial are printed out all category names - that's okay, but:

1. I do query on database as many times as many categories is there (isn't there a more efficient way to do this?)
2. How can I sort categories by name?
3. How to put this category data into a `select_tag`?

I'd save each category from the `arr.map` loop into an array and this array then put to the `select_tag` tag, but I am afraid this procedure is quite slow, especially if on the page is like 300-400 array such this one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's two main things you need to address here - first is to investigate better use of scopes to query your data. Second is the mantra you should be in the habit of chanting: "Never use a finder in a view".

In your Event model, create a scopes for getting active events, and for events in the last five days.

```
scope :active, -> {where(active: true}
scope :in_last_five_days, ->{ where("events.event_start < ? AND events.event_start > ?", Date.today+1, Date.today-5)}
# though, a range might be better...
# scope :in_last_five_days, ->{ where(event_start: (Date.today..(Date.today-5)) }
```

Now, you can join those scopes to make your controller much more understandable:

```
@events = Event.active.in_last_five_days
```

I presume the Event model has a belongs_to association to Category (since it has a category_id field), and there's a reciprocal has_many in the Category model. If so you can join onto this association to get all of the categories for the active events in the last five days.

```
@categories = Category.joins(:events).merge(@events)
```

But there's some rather unidiomatic use of partials, and locals going on in your view - the `_event` partial would normally be expected to render a single event, rather than as yours seems to do, iterate a hash of events grouped by date, and show the category of each event - and you're doing that the rather long way round - you *could* just do the following:

```
@events = Event.include(:category).where("active = '1' AND event_start < ? AND event_start > ?", Date.today+1, Date.today-5).order(created_at: :desc).group_by { |r| r.event_start.to_date }

- e.each do |key, arr|
  - arr.each do |event|
    %div= event.category.category_name
```